# D3 - start y.domain and min value

Tags: d3.js

I have a stackblitz here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/d3-start-above-zero-pvqfqa?embed=1&file=index.js&hideNavigation=1

I have a line chart with a fill.

I would like the y-axis to start at 200 - the min value

I can set this on the y.domain like so

```
y.domain([200, d3.max(data, function(d) { 
    return d.value; 
})]);
```

How can I do this dynamically using d3.min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.value));
```